# Unicode typewriter-like font or Unicode alternative for P22 Typewriter Font

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I would like to add my page the look and feel as it was written using a typewriter. I have found a marvellous [P22 Typewriter Font](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/P22-Typewriter-Regular) that just does the job.

[image]

Unfortunately, it is not an Unicode font and a language-specific characters (Polish in my case) are not shown / printed out<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Is there any Unicode alternative, as close to P22 Typewriter Font as possible, or any other that could give as close to typewriter experience as possible, but with full Unicode support? So that texts in many / most / all modern language would be printed correctly?

<sup>1</sup><sub>An weird thing, at least to me, is that non-existing national characters are simply not printed at all, being replaced by a rectangles rather than being substituted by any existing font, i.e. Times New Roman etc. But, that's just a side note, neither a problem for me nor a scope of this question.</sub>

Comment: UTF-8 is a string encoding format. You may mean "Unicode".

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Are you willing to buy a font. It is usually possible to make your own font quite quickly if you limit the character set to say one language (mono space and after that typewriter fonts that dont need many kerning pairs kerning tables even easier to make). Adding more languages increases cost to author, and giving it out for free might be too much asked. Anyway you could distress a existing free typewriter font shouldn't take more than a few hours.

Comment: A note to your note: it is perfectly normal that an unavailable character is replaced with the font's standard `.notdef` glyph. It is a visible rectangle, rather than "not printed", so you can *see* something is missing. Automatically replacing such characters with another font is an application thing – and it may lead to unwelcome surprises if the font fallback looks very different (which unavoidably would be the case with such a typical design). What application(s) are you using?

Comment: @joojaa Certainly, I'd consider buying a paid font or paying for creating a font for me. Especially that I only need a single language (Polish) and that for example P22 already have some of my language characters, so the possible amendment should by, as you say, not too much time consuming. Unfortunately, I have no idea, where to look for such services.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you for your detailed clarification. I am using Microsoft Word 2010 for Windows 10 and AFAIK it was _always_ performing font substitutions. In my past I've seen hundreds of non-Unicode fonts with Times New Roman substitution in this very same Word 2010. P22 Typewrite Font is first or one of really, really many where I see rectangles instead.

Answer (score 3):

While googling around the [1001fonts.com](https://www.1001fonts.com/) turned out to be a miracle answer to my question.

Mostly because:

- it has an amazing [collection of typewriter-like fonts](https://www.1001fonts.com/typewriter-fonts.html?page=1&items=10) (137 when writing this),
- **most fonts are free for private use and many are free for commercial usage**,
- it has an on-line test tool, which allows to type any text and validate support for given language or character set without downloading the files.

[image]

With just a ten minutes of quick work I managed to locate seven fonts that:

- are purely typewriter-like,
- supports Polish language's national characters,
- are free for commercial or private usage (donation encouraged!).

This list included:

1. Free For Commercial Use:

- [Kingthings Trypewriter 2](https://www.1001fonts.com/kingthings-trypewriter-2-font.html),
- [Gabriele](https://www.1001fonts.com/gabriele-font.html),
- [Special Elite](https://www.1001fonts.com/special-elite-font.html), and
- [Veteran Typewriter](https://www.1001fonts.com/veteran-typewriter-font.html).

2. Free For Personal Use only:

- [JMH Typewriter](https://www.1001fonts.com/jmh-typewriter-font.html),
- [Bohemian](https://www.1001fonts.com/bohemian-typewriter-font.html), and
- [Punktype](https://www.1001fonts.com/punktype-font.html).

Far, far more than I expected.